# Flip a matrix for scatter plot

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I want to flip an "arc" to the right side. I have tried imrotate but it gives me "arc" facing down instead of right side as shown in figure below. Please have a look at the [code](https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/03/14/fitting-a-circle-easily/) I am using. Thank you in advance.

```
 R = 8; x_c = 5; y_c = 8;
thetas = 0:pi/499:pi;
xs = x_c + R*cos(thetas);
ys = y_c + R*sin(thetas);

% Now add some random noise to make the problem a bit more challenging:
mult = 0.5;
xs = xs+mult*randn(size(xs));
ys = ys+mult*randn(size(ys));

c = linspace(1,50,500);

D = [xs' ys'];
Dx = imrotate(D, 180, 'crop');
Dy=Dx;
Dy = imrotate(Dy, 180, 'crop') ;
subplot(211)
scatter(Dx(:,1), Dx(:,2), 140,  c, 'filled', 'LineWidth',1.5) 
subplot(212)
scatter(Dy(:,1), Dy(:,2),[],c,  'd','LineWidth',1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really mean rotation or do you mean reflection? I'm thinking you maybe actually want fliplr from your explanation since you used the word "flip".

Comment: I meant reflection, I should update title of this question. I have tried fliplr command, it shows similar results as in the figure above.

Comment: so just reflect via `Dx(:,1)= -Dx(:,1)+2*mean(Dx(:,1));`

Comment: @bla It works, could you please add an answer so that I can accept. Also, please add some explanation on why we need to add `2 * mean (Dx(:,1))` and subtract from `Dx(:,1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to reflect the distribution for `Dx`. The operation of reflection means take `x` and make it `-x`.

Here the x-axis for `Dx` is `Dx(:,1)`, so at first we need to write `Dx(:,1) = - Dx(:,1)`.

When you do so and plot you'll see that the values of your x-axis has shifted to negative values. Maybe that is good enough for your purpose and that's it.

If I understand you correctly, this is not enough. Now, in order to bring this distribution back to positive x-axis value it needs to be **translated**. 
 This means:

`Dx(:,1) = - Dx(:,1) + some number that translated x-axis to positive values`.

you can choose that number by first taking the average (or center of mass) of the distribution, i.e. `mean(Dx(:,1))`, this is the value around which your value are distributed. If you only subtract the mean from the distribution you end up with values around zero, to bring it to the same distance on the positive side you need to subtract another time that mean.

`Dx(:,1) = - Dx(:,1) + 2 * mean(Dx(:,1))`

Reading this line means that the `mean(Dx)` is the calculated before the reflection so it has a positive value...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to set the 'XDir' property of the axes to 'reverse':

```
set(gca,'XDir','reverse')
```

This flips the axes, so it increases to the left instead of to the right. The data plotted is still identical, it is just shown differently. This might or might not be what you're after.

Answer (score -1):

`fliplr` can work, but not with your `Dx` array, as it is.  `fliplr` operates on the data, not the image, so with an array of size 500 x 2, the function flips x-values for y-values, and vice versa, which is why you get a rotation instead of a reflection.

One way to get `fliplr` to work is to capture the image data after you plot it, then flip it:

```matlab
scatter(Dx(:,1), Dx(:,2), 140,  c, 'filled', 'LineWidth',1.5)
f = getframe;
flipped = fliplr(f.cdata);
imshow(flipped)
```